# Which loyality program should I use for my Aerolineas Argentinas flights?

Tags: loyalty-programs, recommendations, aerolineas-argentinas

In December 2013 and January 2014 I did a couple of flights with Aerolineas Argentinas. Since some of them would let me earn a lot of miles, I'd like to join a loyalty program where I'll get miles for the flights.

Aerolineas Argentinas is member of [Skyteam](https://www.skyteam.com/Why-SkyTeam/Frequent-Flyer-Program/). Each of the member airline has its own loyalty program. Currently, out of these loyalty programs, I'm only member of Flying Blue. However, Flying Blue requires the original boarding documents which I don't have anymore. I tried to join Aerolineas Plus to get my miles there, but they require that you already have been a member at the time of the flights.

So my question is: Which loyalty program can/should I choose so that I still can get miles for these flights?

Comment: Are you sure that FlyingBlue need the boarding pass? Isn't the ticket number and invoice enough?

Comment: Hmm not 100% sure, they write on their homepage: "Please upload proof of your flight, ticket number and reservation class". I attached my booking confirmation, but this wasn't enough.

Comment: You should've got an e-ticket receipt when you booked, that's more likely to work than a booking confirmation email. Worth trying with that?

Comment: Not every program will give you credit for flights made before enrollment: Czech says 3 months for flights on Czech, Delta says 30 days for flights on Delta, but Korean gives you nada. Finding a program that will give you credit for *partner* flights made before enrollment seems even less likely; Aeroflot explicitly refuses it.

Comment: After a couple of emails, the E-ticket number and a invoice was enough and they accepted it as a proof. So the problem is solved. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that Flying Blue is not as restrictive as mentioned on their homepage. Even though they require you to hand in the original boarding pass, it is possible to get the miles with just the e-ticket number and any kind of proof that you paid for the flights. In my case, this was an invoice.

So the answer to the question is: Send FlyingBlue an email and tell them your problem.